# Docker - How to Inspect Container for Volume Path?

Tags: json, docker, inspect

So from the docs, I can query my container for its volumes:

```
docker inspect --format="{{.Volumes}}" container
```

this returns paths in the format:

```
map[/container/path/1:/host/path/1 /container/path/2:/host/path/2]
```

My question is, how do you extract a single path out of this returned data? Say I only wanted the `/host/path/2` so i could use it in a script to backup the data in that volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `--format` is a standard go [text/template](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) expression.  If you want to get the host path corresponding to a particular container path, you could do this:

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{index .Volumes "/container/path/1"}}' container
/host/path/1
```

If you want to produce a list of host:container pairs, you could do this:

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{range $key, $value := .Volumes}}{{printf "%s:%s\n" $key $value}}{{end}}'
```

Which would get you:

```
/container/path/1:/host/path/1
/container/path/2:/host/path/2
```

In this example, we're taking advantage of this syntax:

> A pipeline inside an action may initialize a variable to capture the
>   result. The initialization has syntax
>
> ```
> $variable := pipeline
> ```
>
> where $variable is the name of the variable. An action that declares a
>   variable produces no output.
>
> If a "range" action initializes a variable, the variable is set to the
>   successive elements of the iteration. Also, a "range" may declare two
>   variables, separated by a comma:
>
> ```
> range $index, $element := pipeline
> ```
>
> in which case $index and $element are set to the successive values of
>   the array/slice index or map key and element, respectively. Note that
>   if there is only one variable, it is assigned the element; this is
>   opposite to the convention in Go range clauses.